# quantikz/tikz, I can't remove the borders from some operators without obscuring letters

Tags: tikz-styles, quantikz

Depending on the definition of parameters I can remove or keep the boarders of an operation.

For example, this code

```
\begin{quantikz}
    &\gate[style={red!10}]{X} & \measure[style={fill=gray!10}]{Z}
\end{quantikz}
```

creates this

[image]

You can see that the `\gate` X has no boarders while `\measure` has.

If I try to apply the same criteria used for `\gate`. Namely

```
\begin{quantikz}
    &\gate[style={red!10}]{X} & \measure[style={gray!10}]{Z}
\end{quantikz}
```

This is what happens

[image]

The Z disappeared.

Am I doing something wrong? How can I overcome this?

Comment: Fragments of code are almost useless, so hard to say without usable code. But try `draw=none`.

Comment: It worked, thanks.

Comment: With `gray!10` you just define the color of *everything*, fill, stroke and text to be `gray!10`, so the Z is not visible against the background in the same color, but it is still there. With `draw=...` you can set the color for the border of a node, with `text=...` you can set the color for the text.